# How Can i Implementing Swipe View in ActionTab and Fragments within Multiple Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on `Actionbar.TabListener` and `Fragments`
Tab.

Fragments contains multiple `Fragments` that are generated via clickable buttons on each tabbed `Fragments`.

My `MainActivity` and other files are shown below:

My main activity is as follows:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new Mcx();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("A");
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("B");
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("C");

        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
    }
}
```

And `TabListener` file that `extends ActionBar.Tablistener`:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    Fragment fragment;

    public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id. fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml` is configured as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Question:**

Given what I have implemented above, how could I go about implementing both `ActionTab` and `Fragment View` as a swipe view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the google i found that we can achieve swipe view in fragments with Tab with the use of ViewPager

Go to Android Studio and select TabActivity (Swipe with ViewPager template)

first we have to extend fragmentAcitvity with MainActivity, and that should be implemented with ActionBar.TabListener

The Code is as follows..

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    ActionBar actionbar;
    public static ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        actionbar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);

        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("TAB3").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("TAB").setTabListener(this));
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

XML for MainActivity .... activity_mail.xml will be...

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

FragmentpageAdapter

```
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0){
            case 0: return new Tab1Fragment();

            case 1: return new Tab2Fragment();

            case 2: return new Tab3Fragment();

            case 3: return new Tab4Fragment();

            default:break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return getPageTitle(4);
    }
}
```

If you take By default Template in Android Studio as mentioned above there will be an fragment_main file also ...

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After that implement all Fragments with related Tabs that you declared and added in FragmentPagerAdapter and MainActivity.

You have to set activity theme in Androidmenifest.xml

```
"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

and also in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```