# How to replace Fragment inside Viewpager , Which Id should i give to replace fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I had problem to achieve Swipe view in Fragments with ActionBar.TabListener, i found that solution by googling... now i stuck on replacing fragments in each tabs..

My each Tabs  Contains the Fragments and in each Fragments I have Button with setONclickListener that should replace another fragment

The MainActivity and FragmentPagerAdapter classes that I have used in code is mentioned in my previous question, that link is as follows..

[How Can i Implementing Swipe View in ActionTab and Fragments within Multiple Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452836/how-can-i-implementing-swipe-view-in-actiontab-and-fragments-within-multiple-fra?answertab=active#tab-top)

Now in each fragments i used FragmentTransaction with xml layout ids but it overlaps the old Fragment ...

I have also chked with main.xml view pager id but that also didn't work..

FragmentTab1 is ...

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    Button A, B;
    LinearLayout rl;

    public FragmentTab1 () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.e_layout, container, false);
        A=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.intra);
        B=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.del);
        rl= (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ie1);

        A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentTab1A i= new FragmentTab1A ();
                FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.ie1, i);
                ft.remove(Equity.this);

/*
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);*/

                ft.commit();


            }


        });
        Del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTab1B d= new FragmentTab1B ();
                FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.ie1, d);


                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

    return rootView;
    }

}
```

FragmentTab1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ie1"
    >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Intra Day"

    android:id="@+id/intra"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Del"

        android:id="@+id/del"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As given above in FragmentTab1 i have replaced with A and B button with the use of id of FragmentTab1.xml 's LinearLayout id

I also tried with id of viewpager in activity_main.xml

Please Share solution..

Thanks.

Comment: The replacement code should go into the viewpager adapter

Comment: Thanks for replying... Can you give more explanation , i am beginner

Comment: I assume you're using a pager adapter alongside with these tabs?

Comment: yes i am using FragmentPagerAdapter... but can we put that replacement code inside that "FragmentPagerAdapter" ? because i have buttons inside each Fragments with that i want to switch fragments.. like i gave code for FragmentTab1, as above..